# combobox signal when specific item selected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I got a GUI built with QtDesigner with a combo box and several tabs. I want to make it so depending on the item selected in the combobox, only certain tabs will be enabled.

Below is an example with a combo box with 4 items and a tab widget with 4 tabs. What I want to do is when '1' is selected, only Tab 1 will be enabled, when '2' is selected then Tab 1 and Tab 2 will be enabled, etc.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(295, 177)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.formLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayout_5.setObjectName("formLayout_5")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.formLayout_5.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_5)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.formLayout_5.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.comboBox)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setEnabled(True)
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.formLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.tab)
        self.formLayout_4.setObjectName("formLayout_4")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout_4.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.formLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.formLayout_3.setObjectName("formLayout_3")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout_3.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.formLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.formLayout_2.setObjectName("formLayout_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.tab_4)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_4)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_4)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.formLayout_5.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.tabWidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 295, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ComboBox"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Some text."))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Some text."))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Some text."))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 3"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Some text."))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 4"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @S.Nick - I've added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`currentIndexChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) signal to get the selected index, then you have to iterate over the tabs setting which should be enabled or not using [`setTabEnabled()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#setTabEnabled):

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    # ...


# https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.onCurrentIndexChanged)
        self.onCurrentIndexChanged(self.comboBox.currentIndex())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onCurrentIndexChanged(self, index):
        for i in range(self.tabWidget.count()):
            self.tabWidget.setTabEnabled(i, index >= i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @Vlad I recommend you for a next occasion you should show an attempt even if it is unsuccessful, in your code you have only shown a GUI that is easy to create with Qt Designer that shows a minimum effort. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I was asked to provide a minimal reproducible example and that's why I quickly created this to show what I meant.

Comment: @Vlad 1) Your question does not require an MRE since your question is not: "I want to implement X but I can not implement it since I have a problem Y", but in your case it is a request for a new functionality. 2) We can ask for any relevant information and you have to take enough time to provide it in the best way (do not feel pressured in time).

Comment: @Vlad 3) Finally it is said that one should take at least one hour to ask a good question, have you done it ?, I do not think you should have the same pressure as when presenting a job to your teacher or boss, in the same way that I have done it. In conclusion if you want a good answer you have to invest time and effort.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will try to do that next time. It's not that I haven't spent any time and effort on this though. I only started learning Python less than 2 months ago, and this is for a project at university (I'm a chemistry grad student, not a programmer). I spent several days reading stuff online on how to do this, but a lot of the things I read I don't understand that well because I'm new to this. That's why I resorted to ask more experienced people on here. However, I can see where you're coming from and I will try to ask better questions in the future. Thank you!